# Define a bean from external library

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a poblem.

I am working with api binance and I add this library to use all functionalities.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.binance</groupId>
<artifactId>binance-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the code of external library

```
public class Market {
    private final String baseUrl;
    private final RequestHandler requestHandler;
    private final boolean showLimitUsage;

    public Market(String baseUrl, String apiKey, boolean showLimitUsage) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        this.requestHandler = new RequestHandler(apiKey);
        this.showLimitUsage = showLimitUsage;
    }
```

When I try to inject this classe I always receive the following error on SpringBoot

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.binance.connector.client.impl.spot.Market' in your configuration.
```

I have an controller and I use like this.

```
@RestController

public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    private Market market;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(market.ping());
    }

}
```

I try to add the class with ComponentScan.

The code of external library is only for read.

Comment: As the library is not using Spring in any way you have to create the bean on your own: `public @Bean Market market() { return new Market(...); }`

Comment: The bean is with constructor only and when I define I receive the same error :( @SimonOelerich